how to set the dynamic “destination” in the properties for an agent moved by a crane
I can’t figure out how to set the dynamic “destination” in the properties for an agent moved by a crane (the “MoveByCrane” block) to "Cell" in "Storage". I place the agent using the "Store" block in the "StorageSystem".
I tried to release it like this 1, it works, but I want to implement dynamic change of parameters not of the storage, but of the cell 2. Want to implement the following logic: checking the available cells in the storage, finding XYZ an available cell and moving the crane to this coordinate.

Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Could you clarify a little and share some screenshots? It is a little confusing currently :). Also, pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other SOF users. Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Benjamin, good morning and thanks for the recommendations!
Edited and added detailed screenshots in my question. Should I add more information?

thx. However, for "How do I do X" questions, SOF is not the right place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community . Use SOF for very specific questions ("I want A. I think B should work. But instead of seeing A, I see C")
